# How to use FormBase with form_alter hook?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I am trying to **edit** the **node creation form** in order to add multiple **'tableselect'** fields in it. My module adds options in a select field and add an ajax callback triggered by the 'change' event of that select. I want the **ajax callback** to **return** a new **'tableselect'** field.

I have created a custom module and I do everything (hook + ajax callback) inside a **mymodule.module** file.

```
 <?php
use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/*
** Implement hook_form_alter
*/

function pages_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
 if ($form_id == 'node_page_form') {
    $connection = \Drupal::database();

    $query = $connection->select('templates', 't');
    $query->fields('t', ['name', 'tid', 'components']);
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
    $form['select_template'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t("Select a page template"),
        '#required' => true,
        '#field_suffix' => '<div id="dynamic-fields"></div>',
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => 'pages_module_mySelectChange',
            'event' => 'change',
            'wrapper' => 'dynamic-fields',
          ],
    );
    foreach ($result as $template) {
        $form['select_template']['#options'][$template->tid] = $template->name;
    }
  }
}
function pages_module_mySelectChange(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
$header = [
'first_name' => t('First Name'),
'last_name' => t('Last Name'),
];
$options = [
1 => [
'first_name' => 'Indy',
'last_name' => 'Jones',
],
2 => [
'first_name' => 'Darth',
'last_name' => 'Vader',
],
3 => [
'first_name' => 'Super',
'last_name' => 'Man',
],
];
$form['table1'] = array(
'#type' => 'tableselect',
'#header' => $header,
'#options' => $options,
);

return $form['table1'];
}
```

My **problem** is that in order to **create** **tableselect fields** you have to be in a **class** that **extends** **'FormBase'** and **hooks** can't be used in classes I believe. I'm a bit clueless about how to process in this case.

Maybe hooks can be used within classes ?

Maybe I don't need **FormBase** to create a tableselect field ?

Maybe I should separate my code in two parts, like calling a **custom class method** from my hook ?

Any help?

Comment: _in order to create tableselect fields you have to be in a class that extends 'FormBase'_ Are you sure? I can’t imagine why that would be, table selects are just render arrays like any other. Could you explain a bit more what you mean by that?

Comment: Separately, there’s one rule to understand about form Ajax callbacks - the callback is just there to return the element which should be displayed (or some Ajax commands). The actual adding or manipulating of an element needs to be done in the form builder, so either in a class that extends `FormBase`, or in the form alter hook, usually based on something in the form state

Comment: I had indeed a bad understanding of what I should do and not do in ajax callback, thanks your comments helped me a lot !